# How to start the Einstein Bot on specific keyword?

Tags: service-cloud-console, sales-cloud, einstein-chatbot, digital-engagement

I created an Einstein Bot on Production for WhatsApp Chat, I want it to only start only on specific keywords/messages, for example, ="test"

So that the bot doesn't reply to customers, as it is not completely ready.

I didn't find any solution, because according to me, there isn't any variable which can store the first "hi/hello" message from the customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it.

In Welcome Dialog Box, I created a dialog Box and typed a generic message. After that, I saved the response in a variable and in Rules checked whether the variable value is equal to the specific keyword or not.

If yes, call the dialog to another dialog box. Check the attached image for reference.
[image]